# How pass an ArrayList<customObject> from an intent to an other?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an intent which is searching data from a webservice.
I'm trying to pass these datas from this intent to another screen (intent)

searching intent

```
public void setXXX(ArrayList<XXX> xxxData) {
    this.xxxs= xxxData;
    if(xxxData.size() > 0)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, otherActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        alert (getResources().getString(R.string.no_result));
    }
}
```

receiver intent

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            this.xxxs = (...);      

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xxxlist);
    this.xxxList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    this.listView.setAdapter(new xxxDataAdapter(this,this.layoutInflator, this.xxxs));
}
```

How can i use my arrayList<> from the second intent ?

Comment: According to the docs, [you have some options](https://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3). Probably best to use a singleton here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to send Objects through `Intents`, you have to implement `Parcelable` interface for that object. It uses a `CREATOR` to write Strings and primitive types of that object.

[Here is the developer page for it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Once you have done that, you can send that object in an ArrayList like this:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ArrayList<Parcelable> ... );
```

See this method: [putParcelableArrayListExtra](http://goo.gl/lNvlO)

And in the receiving activity, you can call:

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra( String key );
```

[As defined in the API here](http://goo.gl/dV9UN)

Comment: My object have to be serializable ?

Comment: No not serializable, that is a different interface. Parcelable is used in the Android API.

Comment: Ok, it look work. I just have "java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value ... " cause one of my attribute is JSONArray type. How can i use it with the constructor(Parcel in) ?

Comment: One solution: Translate your JSONArray into a String, parcel that String. When unparceling, your get that String and create a JSONArray from it.